# Is it possible have dynamic scrollbar on an html element / tag?

Tags: css, html, primefaces

You can leave a dynamic scrollbar with primefaces p:panel? When I put the div scroll bar is fixed on the page. Is it possible? I would like this div to be positioned according to the user's browser, according to a p:panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A div element can have its own scrollbar. You can add this in through css so, if your panel creates a div and if that div has an ID that you can see at runtime, you can use target that ID with CSS to control the scrollbar using the overflow style. Also, to position the scrollbar according to user's browser, you may get your desired effect if you set a max-height on the div element.

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```